# javascript algorithm: Check x/y-points to get if component is a circle or not

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, matrix, coordinates

I have an matrix like this, so I hope you can get the circle outline:

> EDIT 1: **What about the outline?** The outline doesn't includes spaces (so every y-value gets minimum 2 x-values)
>
> EDIT 2: **What is a circle?** Searching for an more ore less "exact circles" like the example below! (nearly same radius at every point)

```
    00000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000001111111100000000000
    00000000000100000000010000000000
    00000000010000000000000100000000
    00000000100000000000000010000000
    00000000100000000000000010000000
    00000001000000000000000001000000
    00000010000000000000000000100000
    00000010000000000000000000100000
    00000010000000000000000000100000
    00000100000000000000000000100000
    00000100000000000000000000100000
    00000100000000000000000000100000
    00000100000000000000000000100000
    00000100000000000000000000100000
    00000010000000000000000000100000
    00000010000000000000000000100000
    00000010000000000000000001000000
    00000001000000000000000010000000
    00000000100000000000000010000000
    00000000100000000000000100000000
    00000000010000000000001000000000
    00000000000111111111100000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000
```

and I also have an array like this including all positions of the outline:

```
var coordinates = [
  [13,1],[14,1],[15,1],[16,1],[17,1],[18,1],[19,1],[20,1],
  [11,2],[21,2],
  [9,3],[23,3],
  [8,4],[24,4],
  [8,5],[24,5],
  [7,6],[25,6],
  [6,7],[26,7],
  [6,8],[26,8],
  [6,9],[26,9],
  [5,10],[26,10],
  [5,11],[26,11],
  [5,12],[26,12],
  [5,13],[26,13],
  [5,14],[26,14],
  [6,15],[26,15],
  [6,16],[26,16],
  [6,17],[25,17],
  [7,18],[24,18],
  [8,19],[24,19],
  [8,20],[23,20],
  [9,21],[22,21],
  [11,22],[12,22],[13,22],[14,22],[15,22],[16,22],[17,22],[18,22],[19,22],[20,22]]
```

> What is a good way to check if the coordinates are matching to be a circle?

My first idea was using some code like this but tbh I'm sure there is a way more efficient & working way:

```js
var circle = [[13,1],[14,1],[15,1],[16,1],[17,1],[18,1],[19,1],[20,1],[11,2],[21,2],[9,3],[23,3],[8,4],[24,4],[8,5],[24,5],[7,6],[25,6],[6,7],[26,7],[6,8],[26,8],[6,9],[26,9],[5,10],[26,10],[5,11],[26,11],[5,12],[26,12],[5,13],[26,13],[5,14],[26,14],[6,15],[26,15],[6,16],[26,16],[6,17],[25,17],[7,18],[24,18],[8,19],[24,19],[8,20],[23,20],[9,21],[22,21],[11,22],[12,22],[13,22],[14,22],[15,22],[16,22],[17,22],[18,22],[19,22],[20,22]]

var no_circle= [[13,1],[14,1],[25,4]]


Array.prototype.is_circle = function() {
var min = {
 'x': Infinity,
 'y': Infinity
};
var max = {
 'x': 0,
 'y': 0
};
var center = {
 'x': 0,
 'y': 0
};
var radius;
this.forEach(function(a) {
  a[0] = a[0]
  a[1] = a[1]
 if (a[0] > max.x) max.x = a[0];
 if (a[0] < min.x) min.x = a[0];
 if (a[1] > max.y) max.y = a[1];
 if (a[1] < min.y) min.y = a[1];
});
center.x = (max.x + min.x) / 2;
center.y = (max.y + min.y) / 2;
radius = []
radius[0] = max.x - center.x
radius[1] = center.x - min.x
radius[2] = center.y - min.y
radius[3] = max.y - center.y
    
r = (radius[0] + radius[1] + radius[2] + radius[3]) / 4;
    
if ((radius[0] > r-1 && radius[0] < r+1) && (radius[1] > r-1 && radius[1] < r+1) && (radius[2] > r-1 && radius[2] < r+1) && (radius[3] > r-1 && radius[3] < r+1)) return true;
    
   return false

}

var result1 = circle.is_circle();
console.log(result1)


var result2 = no_circle.is_circle();
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: Computers don't handle "more or less exact" like humans do. Unless you wanted to delve into machine learning solutions, you would need to define what that means, algorithmically.

Comment: Take the most left/right up/down get the center in between those and you are done.

Comment: For what?? I will don't get the information if the component is a circle or whatever, I will just know the center-point. So e.g it could be also a square,... @JonasW.

Comment: @JonasW. Your comment doesn't make much sense, and is a gross oversimplification, if I understand you correctly

Comment: You can try to fit a circle (see e.g. [here](https://www.spaceroots.org/documents/circle/circle-fitting.pdf)) to the outline and use the fitting residual as a measure of how "circular" your shape is.

Comment: And then you can check every point `radius === Math.sqrt( (point.x - center.x) ** 2 + (point.y - center.y) ** 2 )` ...

Comment: @Jonas0000 You'll need to come up with some rules. For example, the edges on the ellipses, ovals, and circles will all be equidistant for each mirrored pair of rows. For example, the distance between the edge of the "circle" in the 2nd from the top row will mirror the distance in the the 2nd from the bottom. They may not be in the same positions, but the distance will be the same. You also need to make sure that each (non top or bottom) row has exactly two 1 values. The top and bottom row should (probably) have the same number of 1 values, etc.

Comment: @JonasW. Like I said, gross oversimplification. These are not exact circles

Comment: Can not really get your thoughts @JonasW. (1).`Take the most left/right up/down get the center in between those and you are done`  & (2) `radius === Math.sqrt( (point.x - center.x) ** 2 + (point.y - center.y) ** 2 )` If I will just check 4 points like you've mentioned I will not be sure that the component really is a circle. Think of squares. And If you want to check all outline points I don't get why you like me to `Take the most left/right up/down coordinate` It would be super nice I you would share some code! Greetings, jonas

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm seems to check only four most distant points on X and Y axis. I guess that if you provide points that represent square shape it will also pass `is_circle` test.

I propose that you do two-stage test with some extra *roundness margin* called `e`. Walk over whole set of points and remember `x_min, y_min, x_max` and `y_max`. Then make check if difference between delta of X and delta of Y is in the error margin i.e. `abs((x_max-x_min) - (y_max-y_min)) <= e`. That checks *squarness* of shape so that it can be circle, not oval. If that test passes then calculate center point `c` at `(x_c, y_c) = (x_min+(x_max-x_min)/2, y_min+(y_max-y_min)/2)` and for each point calculate if radius (distance from any point to center `c`) is within error margin `e`. To save on expensive calculations check if squared radius of each point is within error margin i.e. if `abs((x-x_c)^2 + (y-y_c)^2 - r^2) <= e`, where `r^2` is computed for center `c` and first point on the list.

Comment: Anonymouse downvote? Does writing short comment hurt?